# Where is the root Azure Storage instance?

Tags: azure-blob-storage, databricks, azure-storage, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

I am trying to access logs from my Databricks notebook which is run as a job. I would like to see these logs in an azure storage account.

From the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/administration-guide/workspace/storage#notebook-results

[image]

According to this, my results are stored in the workspace's root Azure Storage instance. However, I can't find any reference to this elsewhere online. How would I access this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation says:

> Notebook results are stored in workspace system data storage, which is not accessible by users.

But you can retrieve these results via UI, or via [`get-output` command of Jobs REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/api/latest/jobs#--runs-get-output), or via [`runs get-output` command of databricks-cli](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/dev-tools/cli/runs-cli).